# Create DB record return wrong data types Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

In my model I have functions for create and find records.

Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Charge extends Model
{
    use ChargeMutator;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->request = $attributes;
    }

    public function add() {
         $result = self::create($this->request);
         return $result;
    }

    public function find($id) {
        $record = self::find($id);
        return $record;
    }
}
```

And I have a mutator to mutate the values.

```
<?php


    trait ChargeMutator
    {
    
        public function getCostAttribute($value)
        {
            return $this->attributes['cost'] = // call function A;
        }
    
        public function getTotalCostAttribute($value)
        {
            dd(gettype($value));
            return $this->attributes['total_cost'] = // call function A;
        }
    
        public function setCostAttribute($value)
        {
            return $this->attributes['cost'] = // call function B;
        }
    
        public function setTotalCostAttribute($value)
        {
            return $this->attributes['total_cost'] = // call function B;
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
class ChargesController extends Controller
{
    use ValidateCreditNoteCharges, Messages, ApiResponser;

    public function addCharge(Request $request)
    {
        // $this->validateAddCharge($request);

        $credit_note_charge = new Charge($request->all());
        $get_result = $credit_note_charge->add();

        return $this->createdResponse($get_result);
    }
}
```

the `$request` is like this

```
{
    "name":"TEST",
    "quantity":1,
    "cost":56.00,
    "total_cost":56.00
}
```

The Problem is:

when I   `dd(gettype($value));` in  `getTotalCostAttribute`

- from the `add()` function the type of `total_cost` value is `string`
- from the `find()` function the type of `total_cost` value is `integer`

in the database the data type for `total_cost` is `int(10)`

I am not sure why is the type of the return values casted into strings when use `create()`

I have searched for this for 3 hours now and couldn't find a solution. i need the data type correctly because accoriding to the data type i do different calculations in my calling functions A  and B

Comment: where is the code where you are creating a model instance with attributes? (which are setting `$this->request`)

Comment: @lagbox please see my updated code, i mean there is nothing special happening there :)

Comment: `dump($request->all())` and see what the types are

Comment: Have you tried adding a `$casts` array to your model https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting and then casting it with the model's `castAttribute` method? Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231779/using-casts-with-accessor-in-laravel-5-3

Comment: @bassxzero yes I tried but it's not getting applied  as well. not sure why

Comment: @lagbox this code is very similar to my actual code like 98% , just changed the class names and column names, other than that it's same

Comment: accessors, `get...Attribute` methods, are not called when setting attributes, that is what the mutators, `set...Attribute` methods, are for  ... so there is a big difference between what you have and what you are saying is happening

Comment: sorry I have updated the function name, let me think about the other stuff you said.